# Find common keys in at least two dicts

Tags: python

I'd like to obtain a dict of the following form (not strict):

```
{65: ['Fresh', 'Frozen'],
 66: ['Fresh', 'Delicatessen'],
 75: ['Grocery', 'Detergents_Paper'],
 128: ['Fresh', 'Delicatessen'],
 154: ['Milk', 'Grocery', 'Delicatessen']}
```

when I have an input which is list of dicts. Their keys may be intersected and values - not. For example in our case we have the same key `65` in two dicts with value `Fresh` and `Frozen`.

This is my solution and I'd like to improve it:

```
outliers = [
    {65: 'Fresh', 66: 'Fresh', 81: 'Fresh', 95: 'Fresh', 96: 'Fresh',
     128: 'Fresh', 171: 'Fresh', 193: 'Fresh', 218: 'Fresh', 304: 'Fresh',
     305: 'Fresh', 338: 'Fresh', 353: 'Fresh', 355: 'Fresh', 357: 'Fresh',
     412: 'Fresh'},

    {86: 'Milk', 98: 'Milk', 154: 'Milk', 356: 'Milk'},

    {75: 'Grocery', 154: 'Grocery'},

    {38: 'Frozen', 57: 'Frozen', 65: 'Frozen', 145: 'Frozen', 175: 'Frozen',

     264: 'Frozen', 325: 'Frozen', 420: 'Frozen', 429: 'Frozen', 439: 'Frozen'},

    {75: 'Detergents_Paper', 161: 'Detergents_Paper'},

    {66: 'Delicatessen', 109: 'Delicatessen', 128: 'Delicatessen',
     137: 'Delicatessen', 142: 'Delicatessen', 154: 'Delicatessen',
     183: 'Delicatessen', 184: 'Delicatessen', 187: 'Delicatessen',
     203: 'Delicatessen', 233: 'Delicatessen', 285: 'Delicatessen',
     289: 'Delicatessen', 343: 'Delicatessen'}
]

common_outliers = {}
for outlier in outliers:
    for idx, feature in outlier.items():
        if idx not in common_outliers:
            common_outliers[idx] = [feature]
        else:
            common_outliers[idx].append(feature)
common_outliers = {idx: features for idx, features in common_outliers.items()
                   if len(features) > 1}
print(common_outliers)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This implementation is fine. It's easy to read and it works well.

A minor optimization could be to use an auxiliary dictionary to track the keys seen so far, in order to avoid an extra iteration to create the final result. But I don't think this is really important.

```
seen = {}
common_outliers = {}
for outlier in outliers:
    for idx, feature in outlier.items():
        if idx not in seen:
            seen[idx] = [feature]
        else:
            seen[idx].append(feature)
            common_outliers[idx] = seen[idx]
print(common_outliers)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use Set operations instead of extra dict/list data structures.

```
output = collections.defaultdict(set)
for idx, o in enumerate(outliers):
    current = set(o.keys())
    for other in outliers[idx+1:]:
        for common_key in current.intersection(other.keys()):
            output[common_key].add(o[common_key])
            output[common_key].add(other[common_key])
```

The output is a `dict` of `set` instead of a `dict` of `list` but that is pretty easy to take care of if it is an issue.